# Tkinter in raspberry pi bash

Tags: python, bash, tkinter

I am able to import tkinter in idle3 and used it to create a simple application and in Idle3 everything works great. The problem is, if I try to start the program from bash, I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter.filedialog'; 'tkinter is not a package
```

Why would the pi be able to run a program in idle3 but not when start with

```
python3 program.py
```

It seems to be that idle3 recognizes the tkinter package but my bash cannot. Any Solutions?

Comment: What does `python` return when run in bash?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that it's being run with `python` instead of `python3`

Make sure the shebang line is `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: On a pi, `/usr/bin/python` is generally version 2 (2.7.9 on my pis). So this is highly probable.

Comment: I have checked shebang to make sure that the command python3 boots python3 and not python2.7